# Does adding an attribute increase load time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, ruby-on-rails-4, load

I'm trying to understand factors that slow a website down. Say I define `Example.all` somewhere on a page. Would adding more attributes to my Example model significantly increase the time needed for the website to load, even if I don't use the said attributes on that page, since the server might have to iterate through more columns?

Comment: _"...significantly increase the time..."_, do you mean in any **measurable** way and **before something else** in your code in a site without 1000 hits per second? With this I don't mean it's negligible but to _notice_ a difference you need to have a _huge_ amount of columns or a huge number of requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends.

Adding more attributes to your Example model will definitely increase the load time. But compared with other factors, it will just be too minor.

A couple things to speed your page loading

1. Cache your `example` model.
2. Use pagination, only load needed amount of data in one single page.
3. Only select columns you need. Example:

   Example.select(“Name”, “Date”).where(Score: 0)

Consider add profiling tools to better measure your load time composition. Check Miniprofiler out and the example how to use it http://railscasts.com/episodes/368-miniprofiler

Comment: Thanks, I figured there would be a difference, but I was hoping it would be minor.

Comment: Yes it would be minor